# logic to solve the new driver's license check question?

Tags: python

Suppose the US has added a new state as Gondor, how to write a python code to validate whether a given string is a new Gondor license plate?
the license plate has the following format: GD-YYYY-xx-xx
x denotes any letter in the English alphabet excluding 'O' and 'I'
Y is an integer.

Comment: Didn't you post this question recently?

Comment: No, i have not, i posted it on StackExchange and deleted it.

Comment: This is an easy regular expression task.  I assume this is homework.  What have you tried?

Comment: I tries this:
def is_gondor_license(plate):
    if numpy.isscalar(plate):
      if re.search(r"^GD-([0-9]){4}(-[A-HJ-NP-Z]{2}){2}$",plate):
        return True
      else:
        return False
    else:
      return False